# How to open new form, pass parameter and return parameter back

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application i open new form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 = new Form2 ("bla bla");
    Form2 .ShowDialog();
}
```

This is my form that i am opening and want to pass back parameter:

```
public partial class Form2: Form
{
    public Form2 (string file)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701734/passing-parameters-back-and-forth-between-forms-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can define public variables which want to return in Form2 and access them in Form1:

```
public partial class Form2: Form
{
    public int x;    //can be private too
    public string y; //can be private too

    public Form2 (string file)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //define some function which changes defined global values
}
```

In Form1:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2("bla bla");
form2.ShowDialog();
MessageBox.Show(form2.x.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(form2.y);
```

Comment: also is needed `static` keyword after `public`