# How to hide main menu buttons as per user login type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, authentication

I have used this code for login form in C# Windows Form application. also, I have created functions for different roles.
How to get user role to main menu form and start run these functions? Please help me, sorry for my bad English.
Are there any easy ways to create user authentication and hide menu items as user role (eg- Admin have full access, User only can access few buttons in main menu) in C#?

```cs
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try
    {
        if (txtUsername.Text == "" || txtPassword.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter vaild Name & password", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
    
        string uname, pass;
        uname = txtUsername.Text;
        pass = txtPassword.Text;
    
        sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Login WHERE username='" + uname + "' AND password='" + pass + "'";
        com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        con.Open();
        dreader = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (dreader.HasRows)
        {
            dreader.Read();
            string status = dreader["user_status"].ToString();
            if (status == "Active")
            {
                string type = dreader["user_role"].ToString();
                if (type == "Admin")
                {
                    FrmMainForm objMfrm = new FrmMainForm();
                    this.Hide();
                    objMfrm.Show();
                   
                                                
                }
                else if (type == "Clerk")
                {
                    
                   
    
                }
                else if (type == "Manager")
                {
                   
    
                }
                else if (status == "Deactive")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your account has been disabled, please contact admin", "Expired Account", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                    Application.Exit();
                }
    
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password", "Login Error");
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code in main menu

```cs
public void clerk()
{
    btnAdminpn.Hide();
    btnDashboard.Hide();
    Reports.Hide();
}

public void manager()
{
    btnAdminpn.Hide();
}

public void cashier()
{
    btnAdminpn.Hide();
    btnDashboard.Hide();
    btnApartments.Hide();
    btnTenant.Hide();
    Reports.Hide();
    Maintenance.Hide();
}
```

So, How to get user role to main menu form and start run these functions? Please help me, sorry for my bad English. Are there any easy ways to creat User authentication and hide menu items as user role (eg- Admin have full access, User only can access few buttons in main menu) in C#?

Comment: Yes, it's win forms

Comment: Your answer will depend on the type of authentication that you are performing.  Are you using Windows Auth? or OAuth?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just create a parameter for the constructer of the FrmMainForm and pass is the value of the role?

Comment: Can you please explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133358/how-to-open-new-form-pass-parameter-and-return-parameter-back